# Force overloading of new/delete for inheriting classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading, new-operator, delete-operator

I have quite a challenge (maybe just for me).

I have several of classes that inherit from some base class A.
All of those classes, should overload new and delete operators.
For now, I overloaded new/delete in class A to return an error message, but I want to be able to recognize those cases in compilation time and not on runtime, since there are a lot of inheriting classes and it is very hard to track them.

Any ideas how can I force those classes that inherit from class A to overload new/delete operators? or any other solution?

Thanks.

Comment: How will making them private help me? if someone will not implement them, it will work, am I wrong? and I'm not sure what deleted is, if you mean " = delete", it is a C++11 feature and I can't use it even if it might be a solution

Comment: Note that tampering with the allocation functions is usually the wrong approach. It won't stop anyone from making, say, a `std::vector<Foo>`.

Comment: Ah, never mind. I misunderstood. (And the answer is that you can't.)

Comment: In our case we want to acheive better allocation and deallocations performance, so it is necessary.

Comment: That's a shame! thanks

Comment: XY problem? Why should they overload `new` and `delete`? Anyway, you can make `operator new` in the parent class private.

Comment: When a child will not implement new, won't it go to the usual new operator and allocate from the heap?

Comment: It's still the wrong question to ask. Think single responsibility. A class should do one thing only. Worrying about allocation is a thing, and so your class shouldn't also be doing that. You should have a separate, dedicated facility to worry about allocations.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The class' implementation of new should be just overloading it and call my memory manager's allocation function.

Comment: can't you just use the word "override" to check, whether it overrides or not?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to implement the new operator private in the base class,
and now I get error in compliation for each class that inherits from A and doesn't implement new/delete operator.